# Automation of Visual Studio 2022 publish action to dotnet cli commends

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

smart people! I am trying to build Jenkis pipeline automating publish step from Visual Studio using dotnet cli.

First about publish step in VS they press option Publish and than they select all flags.
[all the flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdig4.png)

In jenkins I run:

```
bat "\"${env:nugetExeFile}\" restore \"${env:slnfile}\""

bat `\"${env:dotnet}\" publish -c Release -r win-x86 --framework net6.0 --self-contained true -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract=true`
```

Currently I got one .sln file and one .csproj 
the rest of the .csproj projects are

In VS code there is a flag "Delete all existing files prior to publish" I would like to add it as well, but I couldn't find it.

When I compared genareted binares using WinMerge they were totally diffrend. Thank you very much in Advance!

I was trying to specify .sln file before and .pubxml files and csproj, but there always was an error and files didn't publish itselfs. Now there is still an error but files do publish in bin/release/path.

Error message: error NETSDK1099: Publishing to a single-file is only supported for executable applications

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the target csproj when using `dotnet publish`, otherwise you're getting rather undefined behavior, because publish makes no sense on a library.

WinMerge (or diff) on a binary file is useless, unless you exactly know what you're looking for. Dll and exe files always differ between builds, because they have timestamps encoded withhin.

Instead of requiring "Delete all existing files prior to publish" you should rather make sure you start a clean build each time. I'm sure there's a jenkins setting to do this. As a workaround, you can also call `git clean -dfx` at the start of the build.

Comment: If the solution works for you, don't forget to accept the answer (click the small checkmark to the left of the answer)